# How to extract entire columns from multidimensional (2d) array

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to automate an Excel consolidation and conversion (pre-ETL) process as efficiently as possible.  Currently, I am using Interop Excel to read in spreadsheets  as multidimensional arrays:

```
Excel.Range range = ws.UsedRange;
object[,] worksheetData = (object[,]) range.Value2;
```

I understand that Interop is not recommended, but I kept having issues with other libraries, plus needed to use Interop to covert the workbooks to a filetype that those libraries could work with anyways (most require .xlsx and the workbooks I am working with coming in every possible filetype).

So each workbook (I will be consolidating up to 10 workbooks) will be read in as its own 2Darray. Now that I have a 2D array with all of the data, I need to do identify only the target columns that I need and extract those columns in a specified order (so they can be combined/consolidated with other arrays).

Is there some way to create a copy of each array by selecting only certain columns from each multidimensional array in a specified order so that the copy arrays can be consolidated later on?

I have no idea how to go about doing this so any and all tips are appreciated!

Comment: Generally ETL is done in a server-side or otherwise unattended process (i.e., one without a Windows UI).  You will eventually run into issues running Excel interop in anything but a traditional Windows application.  When I worked at Microsoft's support organization, I probably sent more links to KB-257757 than any other: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: Save the elements on jagged array object[ ] [ ]. And consolidate them later. Or a List<List<object> or dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var source = new int[,]
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 2, 3 },
};

int[] third = Enumerable.Range(0, source.GetLength(0)).Select(x => source[x, 2]).ToArray();
```

It gives:

```
3
3
3
3
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response!  I am not familiar with everything you used but if I'm not mistaken, that is using Linq.  I will look everything up so that I understand it and apply it to my case and let you know the results shortly.  Thank you, again!

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to figure everything out.  This works perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help and for teaching me this!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Enigmativity's Linq answer

You could also use an *[Iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators) Extension Method*

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<T> GetColumn<T>(this T[,] array, int col)
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
         yield return array[i, col];
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var cols = someArray.GetColumn(2);
```

Comment: I like your answer better. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much @michaelrandall!  I'll be honest, I'm not savvy enough to implement this just yet but I think I get the picture of what you're doing.  I didn't even know about extension methods.  I'm really starting to love c#.  There seems to be no limits!